# I was *on* Mallorca or *in* Mallorca?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

I may have been *on* some particular island (and probably not *in* it, unless I explored a cave). But in this specific case it sounds better to me to say "I was *in* Mallorca", perhaps because the island is large enough to count as a region of its own. Online I can find examples for both, but of course other Germans may make the same mistakes I make.

Which preposition is correct for a larger island?

Comment: Searching Google in general and Google Ngrams shows 'in Mallorca/Majorca' comfortably ahead of 'on Mallorca/Majorca' (but that doesn't mean that 'on' is a mistake). Yes, the larger the island, the more likely people are to say 'in', and the smaller the island, the more likely they are to say 'on'.
(Note that 'in' and 'on' are not pronouns - they are prepositions. The pronoun for all islands is 'it'.)

Comment: @Sydney Thanks for the correction. That sounded wrong, too...